# What's wrong with this Access query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

What's wrong with this Access query. I get no errors, but no records:

> There are many records that (seem to) match the criteria.

```
SELECT Members.[Last Name], Members.[First Name], Members.Address, Members.City, Members.State, Members.Zip, Members.[E-Mail] 
FROM Members 
WHERE (((Members.Inactive)=Yes) AND ((Members.Deceased)<>Yes) AND (IsEmpty(Members.[E-Mail])=Yes)) 
ORDER BY Members.[Last Name], Members.[First Name];
```

Comment: I'd test the query removing the `where` clauses one by one seeing with which clause you get some results

Answer (score 2):

`IsEmpty(Members.[E-Mail])` will return False for every row.

If you want a condition to select rows where `E-Mail` is Null, use `IsNull([E-Mail])` or `[E-Mail] Is Null`

If you want a condition to select rows where `E-Mail` is a zero-length string, use `Len([E-Mail]) = 0`

If you want a condition to select rows where `E-Mail` is either Null or a zero-length string, use `Len([E-Mail] & '') = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to match `Members.Inactive`, `Members.Deceased` etc. to the variable `Yes` or the string `"Yes"`? If the latter, then you need to replace:

```
WHERE 
     (((Members.Inactive)=Yes) 
AND
     ((Members.Deceased)<>Yes) 
AND 
     (IsEmpty(Members.[E-Mail])=Yes))
```

With:

```
WHERE 
     (((Members.Inactive)="Yes") 
AND
     ((Members.Deceased)<>"Yes") 
AND 
     (IsEmpty(Members.[E-Mail])="Yes"))
```

Comment: E-Mail is a text field. Which of these is correct? 
IsEmpty(Members.[E-Mail])=Yes
or
IsEmpty(Members.[E-Mail])

Comment: If you want to know if the email field contains no text? You could use Members.Email = "".